# enviar mensagem para queue em um vhost

Tags: python-3.x, rabbitmq

A conexão com o rabbit foi feita corretamente, está funcionando.
Se crio uma fila sem vhost, consigo enviar mensagens normalmente. O problema é quando está dentro de um. Não da erro algum, apenas não envia nada para a queue.

Segue meu código:

```
import pika
import os
import time

class RabbitService:

    def __init__(self):
        config = {
            "RABBIT_HOST": os.environ.get("RABBIT_HOST"),
            "RABBIT_PORT": os.environ.get("RABBIT_PORT"),
            "RABBIT_USER": os.environ.get("RABBIT_USER"),
            "RABBIT_PASSWORD": os.environ.get("RABBIT_PASSWORD")
        }


    connection = self.createConnection(config)
    channel = connectionCentral.channel()
    print("Connected to central.")

    channel.queue_declare(queue='hello1')
    channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello', body='Hello World!') # Esse funciona

    channel.basic_publish(exchange='', routing_key='hello2', body='Hello World!') # esse não funciona (a fila já esta criada dentro de um vhost)


    def createConnection(self, config):
        credentials = pika.PlainCredentials(config["RABBIT_USER"], config["RABBIT_PASSWORD"])
        parameters = pika.ConnectionParameters(config["RABBIT_HOST"], config["RABBIT_PORT"], '/',
                                               credentials)
        return pika.BlockingConnection(parameters)
```